# What is XcvPort (used in OpenPrinter function)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm usin the OpenPrinter function and the first parameter the function gets called "pPrinterName"
and that's it's MSDN description:

> [in] Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the name of the printer or print server, the printer object, the XcvMonitor, or the XcvPort. 
>   For a printer object use: PrinterName,Job xxxx. For an XcvMonitor, use: ServerName,XcvMonitor MonitorName. **For an XcvPort, use: ServerName,XcvPort PortName**.

Obviously I'm interested in the bold part. What exactly is XcvPort? I know it seems like a question of lazy person but I really couldn't find info abou this concept. If I would like to open a printer on port ABC I should write:
"**\\MySrever,XcvPort ABC**"?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562762(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's all prototype-like 'programming' :-) XcvMonitor is used if you didn't have an instance of port, XcvPort is used otherwise. All operations on the handle do the same things. But! XcvPort could potentially open ANOTHER monitor dll. Right now I'm researching that.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty close, just add a backslash:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinter", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool OpenPrinter(string pPrinterName, ref IntPtr phPrinter, PRINTER_DEFAULTS pDefault);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

public struct OpenPrinterAccessCodes
{
    public const int DELETE = 0x10000; // DELETE - Allowed to delete printers
    public const int READ_CONTROL = 0x20000; // READ_CONTROL - Allowed to read printer information
    public const int WRITE_DAC = 0x40000; // WRITE_DAC - Allowed to write device access control info
    public const int WRITE_OWNER = 0x80000; // WRITE_OWNER - Allowed to change the object owner
    public const int SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = 0x1;
    public const int SERVER_ACCESS_ENUMERATE = 0x2;
    public const int PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = 0x4;
    public const int PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = 0x8;
    public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
    public const int PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER | PRINTER_ACCESS_USE);
    public const int SERVER_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER | SERVER_ACCESS_ENUMERATE);

    public const int MAX_PORTNAME_LEN = 64;
    public const int MAX_NETWORKNAME_LEN = 49;
    public const int MAX_SNMP_COMMUNITY_STR_LEN = 33;
    public const int MAX_QUEUENAME_LEN = 33;
    public const int MAX_IPADDR_STR_LEN = 16;

    public const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
    public const int ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS = 1004;
}
var def = new PRINTER_DEFAULTS { pDatatype = null, pDevMode = IntPtr.Zero, DesiredAccess = OpenPrinterAccessCodes.SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER };
var hPrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
OpenPrinter(@"\\MyServer\,XcvPort ABC", ref hPrinter, def)
ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, XcvPort is for opening printer ports, not actual printers.